# How to perform actions on iframe after logging from popup window?

Tags: iframe, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Web driver need to perform the following actions:

1. Click on a button from iFrame a popup window opens.
2. Enter the credentials then the popup automatically closes and user is logged in.
3. Perform some action as logged in user in the iFrame.

I am able to perform first two steps but when I try to perform on the iFrame as logged in user facing the below error:

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Session [38d070ab-dde8-4b7a-8f19-043ef05dc1cc] has no driver. The browser window may have been closed.

Please mention if there is any work around?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with driver.switchTo.defaultContent() after closing pop-up?

Comment: @Santoshsarma: This is the answer why add it in comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch back to the original window to perform actions there after your pop up is closed.

As Santosh said use `driver.switchTo.defaultContent()`!